# Pegar todos os rows de uma query

Tags: java, mysql

Amigos, estou com um probleminha: Preciso pegar cada um dos rows de uma query com um loop. Vi um código no StackOverflow, mas ele não funciona. Quem souber como faz, por favor, avise-me.

Segue o código:

```
ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `rankups`").executeQuery();

             do {

                 String nick = rs.getString("nick");
                 String rank = rs.getString("rank");
                 UUID uuid = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(nick).getUniqueId();
                 Rankupbr.DATA_YAML.set(uuid.toString(), rank);

                } while (rs.next());
```

Comment: Qual o erro do código ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `rankups`").executeQuery();

         while(rs.next()) {

             String nick = rs.getString("nick");
             String rank = rs.getString("rank");
             UUID uuid = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(nick).getUniqueId();
             Rankupbr.DATA_YAML.set(uuid.toString(), rank);

            }
```